# Rust mod files in the same folder vs use

Tags: rust

I have the following file structure:

- src

  - function.rs
  - main.rs
  - misc_helpers.rs
  - method.rs

In the `main.rs` I do the following:

```
mod misc_helpers;
mod method;
mod function;
```

because I use functions from these modules. Now in `method.rs` I use functions from `misc_helpers.rs` and `function.rs`. To include these files I want to use `mod` (just like in main.rs) but it gives me the error:

```
file not found for module `misc_helpers`
help: to create the module `misc_helpers`, create file "src/method/misc_helpers.rs"
```

I've found that I have 2 solutions:
(Solution 1) `src/method.rs`

```
use super::misc_helpers;
use super::function::*;
```

(Solution 2) `src/method.rs`

```
#[path = "misc_helpers.rs"] mod misc_helpers;
#[path = "function.rs"] mod function;
use function::*;
```

So I have 3 questions:

1. Why in the `method.rs` I can't just `mod` my way out without using `path` (like in `main.rs`)? I guess that `main.rs` should be considered as a `cargo` module (i.e. root module) and I can only use `mod` to include "child" modules (deeper in the module hierarchy) and not "parent" ones?
2. Why does `use super::` work (in `method.rs`) even though I don't include the files?
3. What's the better solution (1 or 2) and why?

Comment: There's also the option `use crate::misc_helpers;`.

Comment: @Thomas yes, that is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why in the method.rs I can't just mod my way out without using path (like in main.rs)? I guess that main.rs should be considered as a cargo module (i.e. root module) and I can only use mod to include "child" modules (deeper in the module hierarchy) and not "parent" ones?

Because the point of `mod` is to *declare* modules. In essence, `mod foo;` stands for:

```rust
mod foo {
    include!("foo.rs");
}
```

with the modulo that the resolution is a bit more complicated: generally from a module it will look for submodules so from `a.rs` it will look for `a/{name}.rs` (or `a/{name}/mod.rs`), but from `a/mod.rs` it will look for `a/{name}.rs`.

The crate root (the root `lib.rs` or `main.rs` file) is always in the second case so it'll look for a sibling file, but from *that* it'll look for a proper submodule.

> Why does use super:: work (in method.rs) even though I don't include the files?

Because the point of `super` is to go up one level in path resolution, and `method` is a sub-module of the crate root. See the expansion in point 1, same principle.

> What's the better solution (1 or 2) and why?

(1) is the actual solution, (2) is not really a solution, it creates duplicated modules through the hierarchy.

That you had to explicitly `#[path]` the `mod` in (2) should have hinted at that, [it was intentionally introduced to avoid such an unintentional mistake](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0063-module-file-system-hierarchy.md).

An other alternative is to `use crate::function::*`: where `super::` goes up one level to resolve the path, `crate::` starts at the crate root.