# Rust - Use module in a parent directory

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I have a file structure looking somewhat like the following:

```
src/
--clients/
----queue_client/
------mod.rs
--data_evaluator/
----data_evaluator.rs
```

In data_evaluator, I want to use the `queue_client` module, but when I do `mod queue_client` in `data_evaluator.rs`- I get the following error - `File not found for module queue_client`. It only finds the module if I move it into the `data_evaluator` folder.

My question is, how do I correctly use modules that are outside of the consumer code's directory? Apologies if there is an easy way to do this, I did try searching for quite a while and couldn't find a way.

Comment: `crate::clients::queue_client`

Comment: You seem to be confusing `mod` and `use`. Use defines a new module and should be located in new module's direct parent. So your structure should be `crate root { mod clients { mod queue_client }; mod data_evaluator { use crate::clients::queue_client } }`. Also note that `mod.rs` is a bit outdated: since 2018 edition `src/main.rs; module/submodule.rs; module.rs` is the preferred file structure. Also note that you can only `use` items that are marked as `pub`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust mod files in the same folder vs use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67035679/rust-mod-files-in-the-same-folder-vs-use)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a bit confused.
In Rust, you build the module tree.
You use `mod` to register a module as a submodule of your current module.
You use `use` to use a module within your current module.
This article may clear some things up: http://www.sheshbabu.com/posts/rust-module-system/

Aside from that, to use a module that's higher in the tree than your current module, you use `crate` to get to the root of your module tree.
So in your case, `crate::clients::queue_client`.