# RUST: Is there a more elegent way to import mod?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-analyzer

Here is my project structure:

```
.
└── src
    ├── main.rs
    ├── sub_folder
    │   └── mod.rs
    └── sub_mod.rs
```

in `sub_mod.rs`, cargo won't warn me if I import `sub_folder/` like:

```rust
#[path = "./sub_folder/mod.rs"]
mod sub_folder;
```

but I cannot do

```rust
mod sub_folder
```

but in `main.rs` it works!!

Is there a gentler way in `sub_mod.rs` to import `sub_folder/`?

Comment: The `mod` keyword declares a module.  Once the module has been declared (eg within `main.rs`) you only need to bring it into scope eg with `use crate::sub_folder` or `use super::sub_folder`.

Comment: @eggyal ohhhhhhh I missed the `super` key word. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust mod files in the same folder vs use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67035679/rust-mod-files-in-the-same-folder-vs-use)

Comment: @Jmb yes, thx. I fixed it by config my main.rs and lib.rs;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You should almost never use the `#[path]` attribute.** It is for putting source code in *nonstandard* locations, and it is very easy to make a mistake using it. Instead, make sure your `mod` declarations and your file locations match up to each other.

So, if the path is `src/sub_folder/mod.rs` (or `src/sub_folder.rs`), then you should declare the module in `main.rs` because `main.rs` (or `lib.rs` if you are doing that instead) is the crate root, the place where all top-level modules are declared. That is, `main.rs` contains

```rust
mod sub_folder;
mod sub_mod;
```

These two modules are *siblings* within the crate. Then in order for `sub_mod` to *import* (not define) `sub_folder`, it should contain:

```rust
use super::sub_folder;
```

or, equivalently (absolute rather than relative path),

```rust
use crate::sub_folder;
```

---

A tip: If you are using an editor compatible with `rust-analyzer`, you can have it help you with creating modules properly. Don't create a file; instead, write `mod my_module;` somewhere in your existing sources, wait for the "missing file" error to appear, then run the offered fix “Create module”. rust-analyzer will create the file in the correct location for you.

Comment: yes I tried to use `use super::sub_folder` or `use crate::sub_folder`.
But `cargo check` tells me "unresolved import `super::sub_folder`
no `sub_folder` in the rootrustcE0432"

Comment: @SamNormcoreWayne If you get that error, "no `sub_folder` in the root", then you must be missing `mod sub_folder;` in `main.rs`.